# How can I detect whether a BuddyPress page is active from within my theme?

Tags: menus, buddypress

I'm trying to work sub-menus into my theme but am running into issues when navigating to BuddyPress pages (as opposed to standard WP pages, posts, etc.). Basically, what I want to do is have pages (where appropriate) display a sub menu, ala:

[image: http://skitch.com/zamoose/d12ns/about-us-delta-sigma-theta-sorority-inc-south-jersey-alumnae-chapter]

But when I navigate to pages that exist under BuddyPress' control, I get the following:

[image: http://skitch.com/zamoose/d12nu/delta-sigma-theta-sorority-inc-south-jersey-alumnae-chapter]

I'm using the following to generate the sub-menu:

```
if (is_page()) {
  global $wp_query;

  if( empty($wp_query->post->post_parent) ) {
    $parent = $wp_query->post->ID;
  } else {
    $parent = $wp_query->post->post_parent;
  }

  if(wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=0" )) { ?>
    <ul id="subnav">
    <?php 
      wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=1" );
    ?>
    </ul>
    <?php 
  }
}
```

Where am I going astray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I received a direct, easy answer from the folks over on the BuddyPress forums:

There is a template tag called bp_current_component() that returns a boolean. So, in short, to tell if we're currently in a BuddyPress-ized section of the site, we simply call:

```
if( bp_current_component() ){
```

...or, if we want to detect when we're NOT in a BuddyPress area, the inverse:

```
if( !bp_current_component() ){
```

Easy peasy.

So, in total, the code looks like this:

```
if( !bp_current_component() ){
    if ( is_page() ) {
        if( empty( $wp_query->post->post_parent ) ) {
            $parent = $wp_query->post->ID;
        } else {
            $parent = $wp_query->post->post_parent;
        }

        if( wp_list_pages( "title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=0" ) ) { 
            echo '<ul id="subnav">';
            wp_list_pages( "title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=1" );
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '<ul id="subnav">';
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
        bp_get_loggedin_user_nav();         
    } else {
        bp_get_displayed_user_nav();
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```